# Eloquent access list of models via models

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

A `User` has many `Auktion` and `Gebot`. 
A `Gebot` belongs to one `Auktion` and one `User`

I want to fetch all `Auktion` where the `User` also has a `Gebot`

Something like:

```
Auth::user()->gebote->auktionen->orderBy('end_time');
```

The orderBy() should be executed on the `Auktionen` retreived via `Gebot`, which is not possible because the relationship between Auktion and Gebot is one-to-many:

```
  **Gebot Model**
  public function auktion()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Auktion');
  } 


  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
  }  

  **Auktion Model**
  public function gebote()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Gebot', 'auktion_id');
  }

  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
  }
```

What is the proper relationshsip setup and query to achieve this?

**EDIT:**

My current approach is this

```
                @foreach (Auth::user()->gebote as $gebot)
                <?php $auktion = $gebot->auktion; 
                if($auktion->anzeigentyp_id == 2) 
                    continue; ?>
                @include('shop/row')
                @endforeach
```

which is not very clean as I am fetching all entries first and I can't `orderBy()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `whereHas()` which will filter your relation by it's subrelation. `Auktion` must have relation smth like `hasMany()` to gebots

```
$userId = Auth::user()->getKey();
App\Auktion::whereHas('gebot', function ($query) use($userId) {
    //here you need to filter gebots which belongs to user
    $query->where('user_id', $userId);
})->orderBy('end_time')->get();
```

Comment: This sadly does not return any results. My `Auktion` model has a `hasMany()` realtionship to `Gebot`

Comment: Instead of `Auth::user()->auktionen->whereHas()` we have to use `App\Auktion::whereHas()` -> please change it and I wil accept your answer, thanks